# ASPNETCore filter to remove \u0000 from model

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I am receiving in JSON to Web API a customer address with `\u0000` null characters in it:

```
"address1": "1234 New York \u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000 Avenue "
```

This is presumably coming from the user's browser autofill but I cannot find a way to duplicate this.

The UserAgent is `Facebook App 273 on Android (Marshmallow) Samsung SM-S327VL`

I think the safest way is to add some kind of filter to the modelbinder - I'm still using JsonSerializer (last time I tried the new `Text.JSON` package I had issues I don't recall.)

Why is this happening and how can I effectively filter it out for JSON without doing it by mistake for any kind of binary communications.

---

The environment is Angular with material controls, but since the underlying input is still an HTML input I don't think that's relevant. The Android auto-fill may be the culprit but you can't just type `\u0000` on the keyboard so I'm very puzzled. Perhaps it was some kind of VCard (or whatever standard we use now)
at some point? Also temporarily I'm intercepting the JSON in Angular and replacing `\u0000` with `''` but I'd like to be able to test it and see if other characters may be problematic.

Comment: `cannot find a way to duplicate this` Do you mean that this issue only occurs on specific client/device?

Comment: I have no idea! All I know is that the data came from an HTML input field into my model (via Angular modelbinder) and was then submitted as JSON. The customer complained they got an error so that’s how I found it. It’s a real customer whose phone I have no access to. I haven’t yet checked to see how often may have occurred and how many sales we lost. It’s just really bizarre for it to be in the middle of the street address like that.

Comment: `The customer complained they got an error` Does customer report detailed error message?

Comment: @FeiHan no they have no clue. It was tripping up the XML serializer I am using and he just would have seen a generic error. But I looked at the log files and saw his input data. The point is I want to understand what possible browser extension or feature is allowing that in a text box.